# Insert results of EXEC statement into temporary table without knowing the schema of results first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, insert, exec

I'm using an EXEC statement to execute a stored procedure that returns a table-value. I'd like to insert the results of this statement into a temporary table, but I do not want to define this temp table first. Is this possible?

I'm thinking along the lines of how an `SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ...` does not require `#temp` to be defined first. Is is possible to do the same thing with the results of an EXEC statement?

Comment: This has been asked dozens if not hundreds of times around SO and the rest of the internet. The sort answer is NO. It is possible but it requires a lot of jumping through hoops to make it happen. You can utilize dynamic sql and/or openquery to do that but it is not very solid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you are looking for -

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced option',1
reconfigure
go
exec sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries',1
reconfigure
go
```

--In case there are no parameters, use this--

```
select * into #a
from openrowset('sqlncli','server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes','exec dbo.yourprocedure')
```

--In case there are parameters in stored procedure, use this---

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @param1 varchar(100)

set @sql = 'select * into #a
from openrowset(''sqlncli'',''server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes'',''exec dbo.yourprocedure ''' + @param1 + ')'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```